# Three.js emissive intensity breaks the program

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new to three.js and have encountered a problem I can't seem to figure out. I'm following this [3D text guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5F75a2BLhI) and everything works fine until I add `textMesh.material[0].emissiveIntensity = glow;` (found in the last section of the video starting at timestamp 6:44).

It worked just fine the first compile with the 3D text displaying, the glow working, and the environment loading. I changed the position of the 3D text using `textMesh.position.x = 10` and after the second compile, the whole environment including the text just disappears and shows only a blank screen.

I `ctrl-z`'d in VScode to revert back to before I made the text position change and still a blank screen.

Here is my code:

```
import './style.css'
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
import { TTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/TTFLoader';
import { FontLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader';
import { TextGeometry } from 'three/examples/jsm/geometries/TextGeometry';
import { Reflector } from 'three/examples/jsm/objects/Reflector.js';


/* CREATE CAMERA */

  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 100, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 1000);
  camera.position.setZ(65);
  camera.position.setX(300);
  camera.position.setY(20);

/* END CAMERA */


/* CREATE SCENE & FOG */

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var setcolor = 0x707070;

  //scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(setcolor, 1, 100);
  //scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(setcolor, 0.05);

/* END SCENE & FOG */



/* CREATE RENDERER */

  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, alpha: true } );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  renderer.setAnimationLoop( animation );
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

/* END RENDERER */


/* CREATE ORBIT CONTROLS */

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

/* END ORBIT CONTROLS */


/* CREATE LIGHTS */
  const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xaaaaaa)
  scene.add(ambientLight)

  const light1 = new THREE.PointLight()
  light1.position.set(10, 200, 10)
  light1.castShadow = true
  light1.shadow.bias = -0.0002
  light1.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048
  light1.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048
  scene.add(light1)

  let glow = 0.5;
  const textReactLight = new THREE.RectAreaLight( 0xf9d71c, glow, 150, 30);
  scene.add( textReactLight );
  textReactLight.position.set( 5, 23, 5 );
  textReactLight.lookAt( 0, 0, 120 );

/* END LIGHTS */


/* CREATE 3D FONT */
  let text = "B\nR\nY\nC\nE";
  let textMesh;

  const loader = new FontLoader();
  loader.load('node_modules/three/examples/fonts/droid/droid_serif_regular.typeface.json', function (font) {
    const textGeometry = new TextGeometry(text, {
      font: font,
      size: 12,
      height: 5,
      curveSegments: 12,
      bevelEnabled: true,
      bevelThickness: 5,
      bevelSize: 2,
      bevelOffset: 2,
      bevelSegments: 15
    });

    textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, [
      new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ emissive: 0xf9d71c, emissiveIntensity: glow }),
      new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff })
    ]);

    scene.add( textMesh );

    textMesh.position.y = 278;
    textMesh.position.x = 22
    textMesh.position.z = -10

    textMesh.rotation.y = Math.PI / 2

    textMesh.castShadow = true;
    textMesh.receiveShadow = true;

  })




/* CREATE CITY */

  // Floor
  const floorTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('images/Concrete044B_2k_Color.jpg');
  const floorNormalTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('images/Concrete044B_2k_NormalDX.jpg');
  const floor = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1000, 1000 ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: floorTexture,
      normalMap: floorNormalTexture,
      })
  );
  floor.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 );
  scene.add(floor);

  //Buildings
  const building1Texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('images/Facade002_4k_Color.jpg');
  const building1 = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 70, 45 ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: building1Texture,
    })
  );
  building1.position.y = 35
  building1.position.x = -50
  building1.position.z = -20
  //scene.add( building1 );

  const building2Texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('images/Facade005_4k_Color.jpg');
  const building2 = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry( 150, 500, 150 ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: building2Texture,
    })
  );
  building2.position.y = 50
  building2.position.x = -50
  building2.position.z = -75
  scene.add( building2 );

  const building3Texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('images/Facade006_4k_Color.jpg');
  const building3 = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry( 35, 85, 35 ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: building3Texture,
    })
  );
  building3.position.y = 35
  building3.position.x = -50
  building3.position.z = 35
  //scene.add( building3 );


/* END CITY CREATION */



// Window resize update
window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false)
function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
    animation()
}

//Animation
function animation() {

  glow = Math.random() + 1;
  textMesh.material[0].emissiveIntensity = glow; //this is the line causing problems
  textReactLight.intensity = glow;


  controls.update();
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

**When I remove `textMesh.material[0].emissiveIntensity = glow;` from the main animate function, the environment loads right back up with no problem.**

My question being: why does the environment, or should I say everything, disappearing from the page when that line is added even though it worked the first time?

Comment: `glow = Math.random() + 1;` is going to be a value larger than 1. Maybe `emissiveIntensity` expects a value between 0 and 1 ? I am just guessing here as I do not know for sure.

Comment: @2pha I originally had the value 1 as 0.6 so that isn't what's breaking it. I forgot to mention that, my apologies.